# UITextView add background image in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitextview, ios10

I am trying for add image as background of UITextview

```
 textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Background")!)
```

Output is :-

[image]

Textview not display single image ?

Comment: Instead of setting `backgroundColor` try this way `textView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "Background")!.cgImage`

Comment: patternImage says a lot about what you should expect.

Comment: Nirav D thanks .. solution working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set image in `layer` of `textView` instead of setting `backgroundColor` with `UIColor(patternImage:)`. So set image this way.

```
 textView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "Background")!.cgImage
```